# Chrome JS: ""? gives SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I understand that the following is not valid JS syntax.

```
""?
```

What I don't get is the error message I get when running it in the console.
Why is it telling me that the invalid token is a `}` character?

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

Any ideas on where the `}` is coming from?

*PS: I've only tried this in vanilla chrome version 35.0.1916.153. It doesn't work in Firefox nightly.*

Comment: Chrome's console probably wraps your input in an IIFE or the like. Chrome's JS console is full of such behavior, you can't really rely on it to produce meaningful errors for syntactically invalid code.

Comment: @meagar You're probably right!